# Java Makefile: how to dynamically compile files inside packages

Tags: java, makefile

I have tons of files I need to compile that are inside 2 directories, and I would like make to find the files on its own.

All the tutorials I found on the internet show how to do that in the current directory but not in other directories.
Here is the code I currently have:

```
JFLAGS = -g
JC = javac

# clear default targets

.SUFFIXES: .java .class

# compile files

.java.class:
    $(JC) $(JFLAGS) $*.java

# directories to look for java files

PACKAGES := \
    Core \
    Card \

# Initialize CLASSES with main.java

CLASSES := main.java

# I have no clue how this works, but someone told me to do it.

.PHONY: default clean $(PACKAGES)

# should add all java files to CLASSES

$(PACKAGES):
    $(eval CLASSES := $(CLASSES) $@/*.java)

# calls sources builder and compiler

default: $(PACKAGES) classes

# calls compiler for each file

classes: $(CLASSES:.java=.class)

clean:
    $(foreach DIR,$(PACKAGES),$(eval $(RM $(DIR)/*.class) ) )
```

As you can see, I tried accessing the directories through iteration and through rules but none of those methods work.

`make clean` gives me `nothing to be done for clean` and `make` gives me `nothing to be done for Core` even though Core is filled with java files and has a .class file strategically placed.

How can I fix this?

The base makefile I used can be found at http://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/~newhall/unixhelp/javamakefiles.html

Answer (score 0):

I used shell find to look for the files:

```
JFLAGS = -g
JC = javac
.SUFFIXES: .java .class

.java.class:
    $(JC) $(JFLAGS) $*.java

PACKAGES := \
    . \
    Core \
    Cards \
    Cards/Abstract \

CLASSES := $(shell find $(PACKAGES) -type f -name '*.java')

.PHONY: default clean

default: classes

classes: $(CLASSES:.java=.class)

clean:
    $(RM) $(shell find $(PACKAGES) -type f -name '*.class')
```